# Dereference before null check

Tags: c

I write function to created the directory and force it to be owned by the user.

```
int mkdir_and_force_owner( const char *path, uid_t uid, gid_t gid )
{
    /* deref_ptr_in_call: Dereferencing pointer "path" */
    if( mkdir( path, S_IRWXU ) < 0 ) {
        if( errno != EEXIST ) {
            lfprintf( stderr, _("Cannot create %s: %s\n"), path, strerror( errno ) );
        } else {
            DIR *temp_dir = opendir( path );
            /* check_after_deref: Null-checking "path" suggests that it may be null, but it has already been dereferenced on all paths leading to the check */
            if( !path ) {
                lfprintf( stderr, _("Cannot open %s: %s\n"), path, strerror( errno ) );
            } else {
                closedir( temp_dir );
                return 1;
            }
            closedir( temp_dir );
        }
    } else {
        if( chown( path, uid, gid ) < 0 ) {
            lfprintf( stderr, _("Cannot change owner of %s: %s.\n"), path, strerror( errno ) );
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but this code get this warning:

Null-checking "path" suggests that it may be null, but it has already been dereferenced on all paths leading to the check.
I want same help to resolve this issue
Thanks

Comment: The `if( !path ) {`  should probably be `if( !temp_dir ) {` . otherwise the test is too late and makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the line where you print the "Cannot open" message to stderr, the compiler has been kind enough to notice that you are, by definition, attempting to pass lfprintf a NULL string pointer. Because it is enclosed in an `if (!path) {}` block. Did you mean to say `if (!temp_dir)`?